# Entity management, with inheritance method calls

Tags: c#, xna, entity, monogame

So, I am creating a game with a Entity system.

public class Bullet : Entity

public class Npc : Entity

public class Tank : Entity

public class Entity

A entity simply has some functions: 
**Update(), Render()**

I created a list like so:

```
List<Entity> entities = new List<Entity>();
```

And I cycle through all of them and call **Update()** */* **Render()**

But the stored *Bullets* or *Npcs* will not get called with their Update or Render functions.

***TL;DR***

How do I store different classes all with a Update/Render function and call it in a loop for all of them.

**Entity**

```
class Entity
{
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, GraphicsDevice gd, Player p, Tilemap tm, EntityManager em)
    {

    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
    {

    }
}
```

**Bullet**

```
class Bullet : Entity
{
    public new void Update(GameTime gameTime, GraphicsDevice gd, Player p, Tilemap tm, EntityManager em)
    {
    }

    public new void Render(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
    }

}
```

**Entity Manager**

```
class EntityManager
{
    public List<Entity> entityList = new List<Entity>();

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, GraphicsDevice graphics, Player p, Tilemap tm, EntityManager em)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < entityList.Count)
        {
            entityList[i].Update(gameTime, graphics, p, tm, em);
            i++;
        }
    }
    public void Render(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        foreach (Bullet entity in entityList)
        {
            entity.Draw(sb);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I assume you want help with this: `But the stored Bullets or Npcs will not get called with their Update or Render functions.`.  But you haven't included the relevant code to help you.  Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Made mistake on example by putting List<Bullet>. Fixed to List<Entity>. If its List<Bullet> it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Entity`'s methods to use the `virtual` keyword:

```
public virtual void Update(...

public virtual void Draw(...
```

And in your child classes, you want to ***override*** the base class' methods by using the `override` keyword, not the `new` keyword:

```
public override void Update(...

public override void Draw(...
```

By using the `virtual/override` combo in your inheritance tree, you are enabling polymorphism, which will allow the child classes' methods to get invoked, even when doing so from a `List<Entity>`.

Link to more info on [polymorphism in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).